# Discord.js bot broke

Tags: discord.js, replit

I read something about this error, but I have discord.js 13.6.0 and node 17.x.x
and I don't know what can couse it.

error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'node:events'
Require stack:
- /home/runner/FittingAttachedHacks/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/BaseClient.js
- /home/runner/FittingAttachedHacks/node_modules/discord.js/src/index.js
- /home/runner/FittingAttachedHacks/index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> 
(/home/runner/FittingAttachedHacks/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/BaseClient.js:3:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like you have installed [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node), but not the actual node version v17. Try uninstalling wrong package **v17.4.0** and install the right version from official site of node.js

Answer (score 0):

The required node version for discord js v13  is node verson of v16 or higher, without it you'll get error like:

1.AbortController is not defined
2.Unexpected token '?'
3.cannot find module 'node:events'

The simple solution is just upgrade to node v16 and the error will be fixed!

Comment: I am curenctly using node version 17.4.0, so it can't be the node version issue

Answer (score 0):

Download Node from the website or NVM (Node Version Manager) if you're using Linux.

NVM link: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm